# Create a custom dialog box on startup

Tags: windows, windows-10, dialog

How do I make a custom popup to be appear every time I log in to windows? I am unfamiliar with this and I want to create a popup like a reminder/note every time I log in. I'd like the popup will stay there until user closes it.

I am using Windows 10 if this matters but I think it should work on all Windows OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do I make a custom popup to be appear every time I log in to
>   windows.

What you could do is:

1. create a batch script as in the below example
2. set the **Message Box Title** and the **Message Box Body** text in
   it for what you want it to indicate

   - `SET msgboxTitle=<Value Of Window Title>`
   - `SET msgboxLine1=<Value Of Window Body Text>`
3. use **Task Scheduler** to create a task executing
   this batch script, and put a **Trigger** on it to execute **At log
   on** for either **Any User** or a **Specific User** (see screen shot below).

   - You might also consider creating an additional **Trigger** on the scheduled task using the **On connection to user session** as well to trigger it at logon from a locked screen too.

**Example Batch Script**

*When this runs the message box will pop up with the title and the message body text as you set in the applicable variables in the batch script and it'll stay there until you press <kbd>**OK**</kbd>*

```
@ECHO ON

SET TmpBatch=%temp%\~tmpLogonMessage.cmd
IF EXIST "%TmpBatch%" DEL /Q /F "%TmpBatch%"

SET msgboxTitle=This is my Message Title
SET msgboxLine1=This is my temp Message Window that pops up at Windows Logon
SET tmpmsgbox=%temp%\~tmpmsgbox.vbs

ECHO @ECHO OFF                                                    >>"%TmpBatch%"
ECHO IF EXIST "%tmpmsgbox%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpmsgbox%"               >>"%TmpBatch%"
ECHO ECHO msgbox "%msgboxLine1%",0,"%msgboxTitle%"^>"%tmpmsgbox%" >>"%TmpBatch%"
ECHO WSCRIPT "%tmpmsgbox%"                                        >>"%TmpBatch%"

START /MIN CMD /C "%TmpBatch%"

EXIT /B
```

**Message Box Looks Like This**

[image]

**Task Scheduler At Log On Option**

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [MsgBox](http://ss64.com/vb/msgbox.html)
- [Start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)
- [WSCRIPT](http://ss64.com/vb/syntax-wscript.html)

Comment: A few suggestions - I would use VBScript to do this and save as a VBS file - VBS is executed by Cscript by default - instead, create a new shortcut in Windows to your VBScript but run it with Wscript - something like "wscript.exe -file "C:\File\ETC". Go to the properties of the shortcut and change the icon. Then link the shortcut to your logon script. It will now look like an authentic Windows dialog message! No command window, and a genuine task-bar icon.

Comment: I would take that into consideration too. Thank you anyway

Comment: I posted my comment as a new answer - I have detailed it more there

Comment: One important part of the scheduled task. you have to use 'Run only when user is logged on'
it DOES NOT work with 'Run whether user is logged in or not' I guess because that makes it non interactive? 
so you might want to change the user that it runs under to .\Users so it runs when anyone is logged in

Comment: Changed my Launchbox shortcuts to point to this .bat when I uninstall a game so I can show a popup that says it needs reinstallation without the ugly error messages. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

> How do I make a custom popup to be appear every time computer starts

Here's one method to create a popup appear at the login screen like a disclaimer.

> ### [How to Display a Custom Message at the Windows 10 Login Screen](http://www.simplehelp.net/2015/09/30/how-to-display-a-custom-message-at-the-windows-10-login-screen/)
>
> This brief guide will show you exactly how to create a custom message
>   that’s displayed before anyone can sign in to your Windows 10
>   laptop/desktop/tablet. One of many reasons you may want to do this is
>   so that you can include information about how to return your laptop or
>   tablet if it’s lost or stolen (ie. a reward message, contact
>   information etc). Whatever your reason, here’s how you change the text
>   that’s displayed right before the “log in” screen in Windows 10.
>
> [image]
>
> *Note:* it’s worth mentioning that these steps also work in Windows 7 and 8, however the screenshots used in this tutorial are specific to
>   Windows 10.
>
> 1. Start out by typing **regedit** into the Windows 10 “Search” box.
>
>    [image]
> 2. Select **Regedit – Run command** from the search result list.
>
>    [image]
> 3. Click **Yes** when prompted to confirm you want to allow regedit to make system changes.
>
>    [image]
> 4. Now you’ll be presented with the main Regedit window. In order to add a message, we’re going to edit two specific registry entries, or
>      “keys”. To navigate to these keys, start out by clicking the small
>      “arrow” next to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**. This should display the first
>      (of several) sub-menus. From this first sub-menu, select the arrow
>      next to **SOFTWARE** to expand that menu. Then repeat the process for
>      the **Microsoft** entry.
>
>    [image]
> 5. Continue by selecting the arrow next to **Windows** then **Current Version** and finally **Policies**. This time select **System** by
>      clicking on it once (instead of clicking the arrow next to it).
>
>    [image]
> 6. In the main window of the Regedit App, look for the entry titled **legalnoticecaption** and double-click it.
>
>    [image]
> 7. In the **Value data**: field, enter the text that you’d like to appear as the “heading” of your message. Something along the lines of
>      “Please Read” or other descriptive/eye-catching wording is generally
>      best. Click **OK** when you’re done.
>
>    [image]
> 8. Back in the main window of Regedit, double-click the entry titled **legalnoticetext** (which should be directly below “legalnoticecaption”).
>
>    [image]
> 9. In the **Value data**: field enter the text you’d like to appear as the message itself. Click **OK** when you’re done.
>
>    [image]
> 10. Exit out of Regedit, close any open Apps (saving your work first, of course) – and then restart your PC.
>
>     [image]
> 11. From now on, before anyone is able to login to your PC they’ll be prompted with the message you just created. They’ll have to hit
>       Enter/Return or click the **OK** button in order to continue to the
>       sign-in window.
>
>     [image]
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.simplehelp.net/2015/09/30/how-to-display-a-custom-message-at-the-windows-10-login-screen/)</sub>

Comment: Looks nice but not what I meant. I want the message to display **after** I login to Windows, not before. And anyway I am using a desktop so someone stealing my computer is unlikely

Comment: @deXterlab97 I know of a way to do that as well... I'll add that as another answer. Thanks for the clarification and answer edit.

Comment: @deXterlab97 I just got done adding the other answer... I hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I recommend - create a shortcut that uses wscript to execute a VBS. I use this all the time to make authentic Windows dialogs like the below.

1. In File Explorer, right-click - select New and click "New shortcut". Then type the following "C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe "error.vbs"" where error is the name of your VBS script
2. Create a VBS script with the name you chose that looks like this

`x=msgbox("Windows Defender has detected one or more viruses infecting this      machine. To protect the integrity of your operating system and keep your files safe, please run a complete scan from Windows Defender to purge your system of any leftover malware.", 0+16, "Windows Defender Has Discovered Malware")`

The 0+16 is the Button+Icon code. Here are the number codes for the icons you can use.

Button =

```
0 - OK
1 - OK and Cancel
2 - Abort, Retry and Ignore
3 - Yes, No and Cancel
4 - Yes and No
5 - Retry and Cancel
```

Icon =

```
0 - No Icon
16 - Critical Icon
32 - Question Icon
48 - Warning Icon
64 - Info Icon
```

You may also refer to them by name.

3. The VBS and the shortcut NEED to be in the same folder.
4. Now, go to the properties of the shortcut you created. Change the icon to an authentic (realistic) Windows error or message icon. Realistically, it should correspond to the meaning of the number you chose for the Icon.

In the end, you get something like this:
[image]

(Yes, I made up the message)