# Warning about locking Windows 7 after inactivity

Tags: windows, lock

I'm working with sensitive data and I forget to lock my Windows frequently when I leave computer. Is there a way how can I lock Windows automatically after certain idle time **and get a warning before?**

I know I can lock automatically after idle, but it's without warning and it's very annoying when I'm reading something and Windows gets locked after one minute. Therefore I need to get a prompt like in internet banking, where I receive something like:

> You seem to be away for a while. Do you want to continue? If you don't react within 1 minute we will log you out automatically.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you just set the amount of time before your machine is locked for a period of time where it won't interfere with you simply sitting idle at the computer?  If you have not provided any input for 5-10 minutes then you are likely not at the computer.

Comment: Because I need to lock a computer once I get away from it and I frequently forget to lock it by Win+L shortcut. Therefore I need to lock it after immediate inactivity. If I go for lunch for example and forget to lock Windows then after 3 minutes anyone can come and do whatever he wants. That's why I need 1 minute lock.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a task in Windows Task Scheduler that displays your message and set its trigger to "after X minutes of inactivity." Just set it to a minute before you have your screensaver set to lock your computer.

If it helps, locking your computer can be done with the keyboard shortcut Win+L. I also must lock my computer before leaving my desk and have found this shortcut to be an easy habit to have.

Comment: @detdet - You can use something like I posted in this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1103341/create-a-custom-dialog-box-on-startup/1103360#1103360 to get a pop up as Twisty mentions if it helps any. You'll need to adjust the Task Scheduler execution accordingly though as mentioned to time it out correctly but that should work.

Answer (score 0):

*The OP posted this answer in their question but it has been moved here to comply with site standards.*

Go to desktop in your Windows 7, click right mouse button >> Personalize >> Screen Saver (down right) >> choose your screensaver as (None) and click On resume, display logon screen and set Wait to 2 minutes. With this setting Windows turns off your screen for 3 seconds /which serves as a warning/ and then locks Windows. I tried to tweak settings, but it works this way only in this combination. Hopefully someone will find it useful in the future.